# UITableView like gridview in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Im implementing the concept of UITableView acting like gridView .I am loading NSMutableArrays data in UITableView.I am loading the array items in UIButtons of a tableViewCell and when a button is pressed then some action should be performed..i.e 4 buttons in each row and no of rows depend upon the no of array items.I could do it partially.I can click the button and next action for button goes as long as there are 8 or less than 8 items in the array.But when there are more than that then I can view the buttons getting added but I could not click on buttons(i.e -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{ )not responding..Couldnot understand where  I am going wrong..?

```
sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int s=0;s<1;s++)
        {
            NSMutableArray *section=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];i++)
            {
                Item *item=[[Item alloc] init];
                NSString *eventName=[[arr1 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Time"];

                item.Time=eventName;
                [section addObject:item];

            }
            [sections addObject:section];

        }
        tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,430,320,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];   
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int numRows=[sectionItems count]/[arr1 count];
    return numRows * 80.0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *hlCellID=@"hlCellID";

    UITableViewCell* hlcell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];

    if(hlcell == nil)
    {
        hlcell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:hlCellID]autorelease];

        hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    
    }
    int section=indexPath.section;
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[sections objectAtIndex:section];
    int n=[sectionItems count];
    int i=0,i1=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        int yy= 4+i1*34;
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(i>=n)break;
           Item *item=[sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];
            CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0+70*j,yy,79,40);
            UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
            [button setFrame:rect];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
            button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.Time];
            [button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i];
            button.tag=[tagValue intValue];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];     
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
            [button release];
            i++;




        }
        i1=i1+1;
    }
    return hlcell;

}



-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    int tagID=[sender tag];
    int divnum=0;
    if(tagID<100)
        divnum=10;
    else
        divnum=100;
    int section=[sender tag]/divnum;
    section-=1;
    int itemId=[sender tag]%divnum;


    NSMutableArray *sectionItems=[sections objectAtIndex:section];
    Item *item=[sectionItems objectAtIndex:itemId];

}
 In Item class I have NSString *Time;
```

my array is like this :

```
(
        {
        Time = "9:00 am";
    },
        {
        Time = "9:15 am";
    },
        {
        Time = "9:30 am";
    },
        {
        Time = "9:45 am";
    },
        {
        TimeStart = "10:00 am";
    },
        {
        Time = "10:15 am";
    },
......24 objects in the array
```

![How can I get all buttons to be clicked and respond to -(IBAction)][1]

Comment: use a customize cell and in cell use 2 or 3 labels as per your requirments.

Comment: good quetion @arizah.. here use custom cell with 4 buttons and also create delegate method for it and handle it with tag if this data is static i mean this format for all dates same then do this logic mate.. :) +1 for que..

Comment: Why dont you opt for ScrollView...

Comment: I have used a custom cell na in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ .Actually I need to perform some action like open an alert box when the corresponding time is selected .So opted for UIButtons..bcoz UIButtons have -(IBAction) event

Comment: @Paras .Could u please explain in detail .I couldnot get u ..?

Comment: @arizah now i develop demo something like your this requirement and here i just give simple example that use custom cell and see the tutorial for this mate.. i post code when i devlop this type of demo mate...

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 6, there's always the UICollectionView. [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html%20Docs) and a [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Answer (score 0):

you can create UILabels and add them to your tableview and use your creativity in order to appear it like grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hopes that you got your answer and if not then impliment following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        int numRows=0;

        NSMutableArray *sectionItems = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        if ([sectionItems count]<5)
        {
              numRows = [sectionItems count]/1;
            numRows =numRows *152;

            NSLog(@"result less then 6 or zero");
        }
        else
        {
         numRows = [sectionItems count]/6;
            numRows =numRows *152.0;
        }
        //return numRows * 152.0;    //145
        return numRows;
    }
```

the problem is that when we are calculating hight of the button.  numRows = [sectionItems count]/1; So manage this line accroding to your need...

Hopes this works for you...